# How to programmatically create and shift list

Tags: python, python-3.6

At the moment I have this in my code

```
up = [1, 0, 0, 0]
down = [0, 1, 0, 0]
left = [0, 0, 1, 0]
right = [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

I want to add another variable I need to know do

```
up = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
down = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
left = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
right = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

And I'm not sure how many variables I need or I might end up needing a lot.

Is it possible to create a list of the variables I need, and then have a loop going through each one and doing this?

I'm not really sure how to go about figuring this out.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: What have you tried? Something doesn't work? [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: yes, it is possible. However, could you elaborate what this is for, precisely? If you're just doing this to create unique identifiers, why use a list? What do the `1`s and `0`s actually represent?
Assuming it's supposed to be a binary representation, why not just use `1`,`2`,`4`,`8`,etc instead of building up (potentially huge) lists?

Comment: @Zinki The 1's represent that the key is pushed, and 0 represents that the key is not pressed

Comment: @Dgameman1 then you should ask a question about how to handle key presses, otherwise this is not clear at all and you will get answers that don't actually help you

Comment: for example, I would answer that you can forget the lists at all and just save the index of 1 in the lists, such that `up=0` and `right=3`, but now that you explained it's purpose the answer might be very different

Comment: @OferSadan I don't see how it has anything to with keypresses. It could be that 0 means dirty and 1 means clean. Or literally anything else. I just need to know how to make things :P

Comment: I tried to give you an answer to what you requested, check it out, i'm just now sure if it is actually helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is called "one-hot encoding", and you could easily do that.
First, build a dict of your "variables", but instead of writing each one as `[0,0,0,1]` just write their indexes. Or better yet, use an indexed list to store their names:

```
mylist = ['up','down','left','right']
```

Then, define a function that takes that list / dict and the "variable" number (which is really the key in that dict, or the item in the list) and outputs the correct "one-hot" encoding:

```
def onehot(mylist, key):
    index = mylist.index(key)
    zeros = [0 for i in mylist]
    zeros[index] = 1
    return zeros
```

Now if your list is as it is written above, running `onehot(mylist, 'up')` will output `[1,0,0,0]`. If you decide to extend that list at any time, you could just run `mylist.append('newname')` and once again, run our little helper - `onehot(mylist, 'newname')` will output `[0,0,0,0,1]`

An alternative implementation is to do all the work in a single list comprehension.  Finding the index can be costly (it is *O(n)*) as the list has to be searched element by element.  Reducing this to one pass reduces the complexity a little:

```
def onehot(mylist, key):
    return [int(i == key) for i in mylist]
```

Comment: alternative implementation: `return [int(i == key) for i in mylist]`  Only needs to make one pass through the list. (Yours needs up to two complete passes because of `list.index()`

Comment: correct, feel free to edit that in at the end as an alternative, I will approve the edit

Answer (score -1):

Adding a value to a list in python is done with append() or extend(). Appending a list of items to a list will place the new list at the end of the existing list while extending a list will place each new item of the extension list to the bottom of the existing list.

For example if you're not sure how many more items you will end up needing in your lists, you can create a function that extends them with any number of elements:

```
>>> up = [1, 0, 0, 0]
>>> down = [0, 1, 0, 0]
>>> left = [0, 0, 1, 0]
>>> right = [0, 0, 0, 1]
>>> def extend_list(list, items):
...     return list.extend(items)
...
>>> extend_list(up, [0])
>>> print(up)
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> extend_list(down, [0,1])
>>> print(down)
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Your output does not correspond to what OP wants.

Comment: My solution was in response to OP's original question. I find it unfair to downvote a valid answer to the question asked after asking clarifications and having the scope of the question changed.

Comment: This is why you first wait for clarifications before answering.